# react-navigation installing caused build failed

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

After I install react-navigation and other dependencies, it keeps running into this error. I have tried to clean the cache and reinstall node modules and pods, but it still returns the same error. Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/xiaoyuzhu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/teamcalai-cmizgjckvaxmiggmtqxtlkdvzzge/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UIResponder+Reanimated.o /Users/xiaoyuzhu/Desktop/teamcalai/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/ios/native/UIResponder+Reanimated.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

And here is my package.json
[image]

Comment: hie! Rita! have you tried Closing Xcode and going to delete derived data of the specific project ?

Comment: have you also deleted the podfile?lock while integrating pods?

Comment: yes, I have tried to delete both derived data folder and podfile.lock but none of them solve the error here.

Comment: then you must be missing some dependent packages of React Navigation package! did you follow the whole installation part?

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure I have all the necessary dependencies installed.

Comment: why RN app dependencies have 'npm', 'i' in them?

Comment: can you please share your XCode version and have you modified podFile in any other case?

Comment: no, I didn't modify podFile.

Answer (score 0):

clear npm cache and Update  **react-native-reanimated to 2.3.0-beta.2 or higher**, in otherWords use

> "npm install react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-beta.2"

And do a **pod install**.